# replace default header using viewForHeaderInSection in a grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to place an uiactivityindicator exactly after the title of a section in a UITableView. I am trying to do it (for the first section of the table) using the 
viewForHeaderInSection. This is something similar with the spinner view in the WiFi setting in the native Settings.app

The code does not give what I want

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if( section == 0 ) {

          UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 16.0)];

        UILabel *headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0, 10.0, 320.0, 16.0)];

        headerLabel.backgroundColor = [tableView backgroundColor];
        headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Choose a Network...", @"Choose a Network...");
        headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0];
        headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:61.0/255.0 green:77.0/255.0 blue:99.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        headerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.65];
        headerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);

        [header addSubview:headerLabel];

        self.searchNetworks.frame = CGRectMake(190.0, 18.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        [header addSubview:self.searchNetworks];

        return header;


    }

    return nil;
}
```

I want my custom view to get position exactly at the point of the default view. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you currently have for placing the activity indicator is fine and will work. The only issue I see is you are not explicitly setting the `hidesWhenStopped` to `NO` if you want it to always be visible. Else, you must call `startAnimating` to make it visible (and call that either way to animate it).

Also, depending on the color of your `tableView` you may not be able to see the indicator. If that is the case, you can change the `backgroundColor` of the `tableView` (if you are using a grouped `tableView`), or the `backgroundColor` of the section header, or the `color` property of the activity indicator.

Those are my suggestions! Let me know if that helps.

> For reference:
>
> You control when an activity indicator animates by calling the **startAnimating** and **stopAnimating** methods. To automatically hide the activity indicator when animation stops, set the **hidesWhenStopped** property to YES.
>
> Starting in iOS 5.0, you can set the color of the activity indicator by using the **color property**.
>
> From [UIActivityIndicator documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIActivityIndicatorView)

Comment: my code is OK, but the UI result is not what I am looking for. I want my custom view to be placed exactly at the default header view of the first section in a grouped table view.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding what you mean by "placed exactly at the default header view". From what I can see, by adjusting the frame, it can be placed directly after the text, just like in the Settings app. If you want it to adjust dynamically with the width of the header title, use `sizeWithFont` `([headerLabel.text sizeWithFont:headerLabel.font])`, and place the activityIndicator to the right of the returned width + padding.